# Pass a function to a function map and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have made my own function:

```
n_hires <- function(data, year) {
  data %>%
    filter(year(DateofHire) == year) %>%
    nrow()
}
```

that I want to pass to another function I have written:

```
df_count <- function(data, f) {
  map_dbl(years, ~ .f(data = .data, year = .x)) %>%
    setNames(years) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    setNames("n") %>%
    rownames_to_column("Year")
}
```

When I run the function:

```
df_count(data = df, .f = n_hires)
```

It returns:

```
> df_count(data = df, .f = n_hires)
  Error in df_count(data = df, .f = n_hires) : 
  unused argument (.f = n_hires)
```

How do I pass a function to a function?

Comment: In the `df_count`, there is no input for `years`

Comment: Do you need `df_count <- function(data, years, f) {
  map_dbl(years, ~ f(data = data, year = .x)) %>%
    setNames(years) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    setNames("n") %>%
    rownames_to_column("Year")
`}

Comment: Oh my... you're right yet again. I need to take a break thank you.... @akrun

Answer (score 1):

The function provided in `df_count` didn't show an input for 'years'.  If we add, it may work (not tested).  Also, the `f` can be directed passed and there is no `.f`

```
df_count <- function(data, years, f) {
    map_dbl(years, ~ f(data = data, year = .x)) %>% 
              setNames(years) %>%
             as.data.frame() %>%   
             setNames("n") %>%   
     rownames_to_column("Year")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating this. Creating `n_hires` function to filter for a particular year and count the number of rows and then create `df_count` to run a loop to count the number of rows for every `year`. Instead of this you can calculate number of rows for each year directly.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>% count(year = year(DateofHire))
```

If you are interested in specific years only you can `filter` them.

```
data %>% count(year = year(DateofHire)) %>% filter(year %in% years)
```